# pip / virtualenv / django installation issue

Tags: django, installation, virtualenv, pip

I'm on a new virtualenv, and trying to install django on it.

When I type, `which django-admin.py` I get back `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` which is not correct, it should be installing inside the .virtualenvs folder.

If I do, `pip install django` I get back:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

If I do, `pip uninstall django` I get back:

```
Not uninstalling Django at /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages, outside environment /Users/username/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/..
```

How do I get pip to install and use django inside the virtualenv?  No idea how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you should be setting up the virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages …/my-env/
```

Then you should make sure that you've activated it:

```
. …/my-env/bin/activate
```

Or, with virtualenv helper:

```
workon my-env
```

Then install Django with:

```
pip install django
```

Comment: I am already on the virtualenv.  I did 'workon envname' and (envname) is on the command line.  Maybe I setup the virtualenv without the "--no-site-packages" flag though?  Would that cause this issue?

Comment: This could cause the issue, as you'll be seeing the global Django. If `which pip` shows `…/my-env/…/bin/pip`, though, you can just use `pip install django`, re-launch your shell (because your shell has already cached the wrong path to `django-admin.py`), re-activate and you should be good to go.

Comment: "which pip" is correct yes, it shows the correct virtualenvs folder.  I relaunched the shell, did "pip install django" again, and got the same error as above though.  Not sure what you mean by re-activate..?

Comment: D'oh, sorry, yes — it won't work because django is already installed globally. Try again with `--no-site-packages` and it should work.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help.  So essentially remove the virtualenv and redo it with the --no-site-packages flag then is the only way?  I'll give that a shot and update in a few.

Comment: I removed the virtualenv (by deactivating it and doing "rmvirtualenv envname".)  Then I redid it using the --no-site-packages flag.  Then I relaunched the shell, and "pip install django" worked this time.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a note. Sometime after these comments were posted, --no-site-packages became the default behavior for virtualenv. Yet I was still getting an issue. This may go without saying but I'm saying it nonetheless, for anyone who has the same issue as I did: make sure you don't put "sudo" in front of pip. Just do "pip install django", no sudo. Thanks everyone

Comment: It was adding 'sudo' in front of the pip command that was breaking it for me. I logged in as root and ran without without 'sudo' and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Like David pointed out, you should tell virtualenv not to use packages outside your virtual environment (using the --no-site-packages flag). That's why "which django-admin.py" returns "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py"

Comment: Yeah, I think he nailed that.  How do I add the --no-site-packages flag once the virtualenv has already been setup though?  Or do I have to remove it and recreate?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new one: `virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv`. Try installing django again using pip: `pip install django` and let me know :)

Comment: Don't forget to do it inside your recently created virtual environment: `source myenv/bin/activate`

Comment: Thanks Cesar, got it working by removing and rebuilding it with the --no-site-packages flag.  Have a good night!