# django not installed in virtualenv, --no-site-packages flag not correcting the issue

Tags: django, virtualenv

The problem I'm having is similar to [pip / virtualenv / django installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976089/pip-virtualenv-django-installation-issue), but the solution posted in that answer is not working for me.

I have created a virtual environment with --no-site-packages using:

```
virtualenv venv --distribute --no-site-packages
```

But when I activate the environment and attempt to install django (sudo pip install django), I get the message:

```
teddy@coolermaster:~/heroku/battle/hellodjango$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)teddy@coolermaster:~/heroku/battle/hellodjango$ sudo pip install Django  
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django in   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages 
Cleaning up...
```

Note that in the above message, pip has found the django installation in my local "dist-packages" folder, not my "site-packages"

And if I try importing django in a python interpreter I get the error: "No module named django."

Should I be using the command "pip install django" instead of "sudo pip install django"? When I try running "pip install django" I am greeted by "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/teddy/heroku/battle/hellodjango/venv/build'"

Could the problem be permissions related (because I am using sudo)? If so why won't it allow me to pip install without sudo? Or could the issue be that my virtualenv is ignoring site-packages but still using the source in my dist-packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up after using sudo:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/teddy/heroku/battle/hellodjango/venv/build
```

Do not use sudo anymore.

Comment: Any idea why I get permissions denied errors if I omit the sudo. As in "pip install django"?

Comment: My guess is that after you used sudo, you created a root-owned `build` folder.

Comment: I deactivated the environmeny, rm -rf'ed the venv folder, and restarted the terminal. But when I try running  virtualenv venv --distribute, I get "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'venv'"

Comment: Do you have the permissions to create files wherever you are doing it?

Comment: It seems I do not. What would be the proper way to give myself permissions to these folders? Thank you for your responses by the way.

Comment: Isn't that your own home directory? What does `ls -la /home/teddy/heroku/battle/hellodjango` tell you?

Comment: I get:
teddy@coolermaster:~/heroku/battle/hellodjango$ ls -la 
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 14:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 13:48 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Mar  6 13:28 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5365 Mar  6 13:28 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  571 Mar  6 13:28 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1434 Mar  6 13:28 wsgi.py

Comment: And after installing the virtual environment "venv", that is listed as : drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Mar  6 15:18 venv

Comment: So why is everything owned by root? Claim your home: `sudo chown -R teddy:teddy ~`

Comment: Ahh I think that was it - thank you so much.  Now when I run the pip command it is downloading django and not giving me the "requreiment already satisfied" message.  Thank you for the help, I am still an ubuntu noob apparently.

Comment: Yes, I see that is the recommended advice from google searching this problem. Thanks again, all is working now!