# pip install Django: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in other virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have multiple Django projects, each one with its own virtual environment.  Starting a new one today, when I pip install into my virtualenv, I'm getting an error that says it's already installed, pointing to a file path from another project -- repos/otherprojectname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

The python path to the current project I'm working on is:

```
/repos/currentprojectname/env/bin/python
```

I'm currently in my virtualenv.  I know because the (env) precedes the prompt, and I just deactivated and reactivated, then deleted, recreated in the file, and activated, again.

When I do pip install django:

> zsh: Users/me/Documents/repos/currentprojectname/env/bin/pip: No such
>   file or directory
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in
>   repos/otherprojectname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

There are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960805/django-not-installing-in-virtualenv) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976089/pip-virtualenv-django-installation-issue) posts with the same question taht I've found, and have tried the answers from both of them.

Python paths and pip still feel mysterious to me, and it would be so excellent to both fix and understand why my virtualenvironments seem to be getting mixed together.

Comment: are there any issues using zsh with virtualenv?

Comment: What does `which python` output?

Comment: Does it show up when you `pip freeze`?

Comment: Can you try to open a new shell and then activate the new virtualenv? Do you still find Django in the other env?